# How do I correctly place figures under tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I'm new to Latex and I'm enjoying the switch but I have a problem with placing figure I can't resolve.

I am using tikzpicture to create graphs and each graph is in it's own file. So my code is:

```
\subsection{Disconnected and Connected Graph}
\paragraph{}
**some text**
\input{disconnected_graph.tex}

\subsection{Simple Graph}
**some text**

\input{simple_graph.tex}
```

This displays fine. Now if I want to add a figure I use this code:

```
\begin{figure}
\input{disconnected_graph.tex}
\caption{**some text**}
\end{figure}
```

The compile displays the following result:
[image]

Could someone point out why this is not displaying as I expected?

Comment: Use `figure[htb]` or use `\captionof` from `capt-of` package, get rid of `figure` environment.

Comment: Thank you, your pointers guided me to my answer. The voted answer did not help me but it did lead me to this which did work. http://goo.gl/cXZIUM